# A Japanese language app for iOS with this particular quality(please read the description)?

Tags: ios, language, japanese

You see, it MUST have this particular quality: sometimes I see a kanji that I don't know the meaning of,unfortunately there isn't any kana/furigana therefore I don't know how to spell it and since I don't know the spelling I can't/don't know how to type it in google translate to find out the kanji's meaning so I think you can guess the problem in other words the keyboard,the Keyboard obviously requires me to know the spelling/how to type it so I want it(the app) to have this additional feature: just like the computer program "paint" where you can use the mouse to draw the strokes of the kanji I want this/these app/apps to have this ability to let me draw the kanji and find the closest and most consistent kanji to my drawing so that I can find out the kanji's meaning and pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use function on google translate to "draw" the symbols. It's available on the app, and I believe it might be available on the website. I found this incredibly useful when first learning the Korean alphabet, as it will recognize symbols or their closest match. Good luck!

Comment: Why not just point the camera at it and let Google Translate tell you the meaning?